# Does anyone know how to make scripts appear on the left?

Tags: interface

[image: **enter image description here**]

Trying to get it to work but is not working.

Comment: Wow, long time since I've actually seen anyone use 2.49

Comment: whats a good one to use

Comment: @Bim_FaDe 2.79 or 2.8x from here https://www.blender.org/download

Comment: do you know how to get models foree that you have to pay for?

Comment: Ver 2.49 can be considered as legacy so I suppose it may not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You have to split the area and change the window type to the *Scripts Window* or *Text Editor*, depending whether you want to execute a script/add-on shipped with Blender or open the actual source code.

1. Place the cursor on the border between two windows, e.g. the 3D View and the User Preferences.
2. Right click and select *Split Area*.
   [image: Split Area]
3. Change the window type to *Scripts Window* for executing a script/add-on or *Text Editor* to load the source code of a script or write your own.
   [image: Change window type]
   [image: Open a script in text editor]
   [image: File browser]

Scripts can also be executed from the text editor through *Text > Run Python Script*.